# I want to analyze this recursive sequence

Tags: calculus

I want to prove the following things and I'm hoping someone will help me.
Step by step how to start solving these kind of problems.
I don't want to bother anybody with this, but I didn't find any site where it has been described step by step.

Monotony, limitation and convergence

$$a_1=1, a_n=\sqrt{a_{n-1}+2}$$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm actually stucked at the beginning I don't know if $$\sqrt(a_n)$$etc. affects the monotony.

Comment: What you can start out doing, since you know what $a_1$ is, you can determine some of the values to sort of prove to yourself if its a decreasing or increasing sequence.

Comment: The thing that bothers me as well is that its $$a_{n-1}$$

Comment: Plugging in 1 to your equation you would get $a_1 = \sqrt{a_0+2}$. We know that $a_1$ is 1, so you can solve for $a_0$ although that isn't needed. Continue with the sequence by plugging in 2 to your formula, and so on to see what's going as n increases.

Comment: When i was trying to solve it i thought i was doing something wrong by just doing it like that but thank you for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to show that either $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ or that $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ to show that we have a monotonically increasing\decreasing sequence. For an inductive argument we start with the base case:

Base Case: Let n =1. Thus we have $a_1 = \sqrt{a_0+2}$. As $a_1 =1$ we can solve for $a_0 =-1$. Thus we have that $a_0 < a_1$. This will fulfill the base case in which we have shown that $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$.

For the inductive hypothesis we can now assume that $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ and what we have shown in the previous step.

Proof:

We want to show that $a_{n+2} \leq a_{n+1}$. We can recursively define $a_{n+2}= \sqrt{a_{n+1} +2}$. We know that $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ by the inductive hypothesis, $\sqrt{a_n+2} \leq \sqrt{a_{n+1} +2}$. Note, if we now define $a_{n+1}$ we have that $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+2}$. By substitution we have that $a_{n+2} \geq a_{n+1}$ as required, thus the sequence is monotonically inceasing.

You can now use the monotone convergence theorem to talk about convergence and finding the limit the sequence.

Comment: It's not enough to show the sequence is monotone to be able to find the exact limit of the sequence, since if the limit is $L$, then $L=\sqrt{L+2}$ must be true, and both $L=2,\infty$ satisfy this.

Comment: True, what I have posted part of the original posts question though.

Comment: A similar inductive argument will show $a_n\leq 2$, which should suffice as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.